# How to handle Windows Errors in Windows HTML/CSS/JS script?

Tags: javascript, windows, exception, windows-store-apps

I see a lot of documentation on how to globally handle and suppress javascript errors in the scope of Windows-Store-App HTML programming, however, I've come across nothing regarding handling errors from Windows itself (such as Win32 exceptions) when building a javascript application.

Is there any way to handle windows exceptions from the scope of the javascript project that I am building?

EDIT:
They are listed as "Win32" exceptions on the console, (I'm developing for windows store 8.1).
Things such as "Violation Access Exceptions" I will attempt to create one and post the results ASAP.

EDIT2: Okay, so what I'm seeing is "WinRT originate error."  To put things in context, I already have global unhandled error events taken care of for all of javascript in place.  However, when running the project in visual studio it doesn't allow these unhandled errors to bubble up to that global handler, and seems to terminate the program on these locally "unhandled" JavaScript runtime errors (which are then throwing WindowsRT originate errors).

Comment: WinRT is designed to avoid raising exceptions on recoverable errors. Errors are reported through the normal execution flow (e.g., a Boolean success code, or a rich status code). What exceptions are you seeing?

Comment: (Also, I'm a little confused when you say "such as Win32 exceptions" because Windows Store apps don't use Win32. They use WinRT.)

Comment: Access violation errors and "WinRT originate error" indicate that you have a programming logic error in your program. You should not be trapping them. Fix the logic error that is resulting in the access violations or WinRT errors. Don't try to catch them, because there is nothing you can do to recover.